# How to use .attr("name") when the name has an array structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, radio-button, selected

I want to get the length of a radio button using the jquery syntax `.length`

The radio button names are like the following obj[1], obj[2] and so on. If I address it directly `$("input:radio[name='obj[1]']:checked").length` I get the correct length.

If I get the name using `.attr("name")` and try to get the `$("input:radio[name="+name+"]:checked").length` I do not get the correct length.

Please help with correct syntax how to address the radio buttons by name.

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the HTML, so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: `$("input:radio[name="+name+"]:checked")` does not put single quotes around the name to force the [] in the name to be considered as a literal string.  I assume this lookup is thinking the [] are operators and is fubaring itself.  I would expect `$("input:radio[name='"+name+"']:checked")` to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is, in 2nd method, you are missing quotes. Use this:

```
$("input:radio[name='"+name+"']:checked").length
```

If name contains special characters including [] it has to be quoted, like you did in first case. You are just appending content of name variable into string, which is sent into jQuery like in the first case.

Comment: Your answer worked for me there is only a minor error on quotes sequence, i finaly used `$("input:radio[name='" + name + "']:checked").length`

Comment: Yeah I see, it was a typo. Fixed.